# How can I find history of ingress portal?

Tags: ingress

How to find the history of an ingress portal, such as a new rename or whether the portal name has changed?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do that.
The only way you can tell if a portal name has been changed is only when you've changed it yourself or if you're familiar enough with the portal to remember its name.
Same for the original location of a portal if it has been moved - there is no way of checking that history.

Answer (score 1):

Officially, no. The intel map only shows the current state of a portal.

Unofficially, yes. But be warned that the community developed tools to do so are not public and are possibly in violation of the Ingress ToS and Community Guidelines. Search them out and use them at your own risk.